# Rails 5 - Carousel without Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to develop a carousel with ElevateZoom like this one here:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3vMt/155/

Main difference is I won't be using static images.  It'll be dynamic images uploaded for different objects so I need to use a loop.

I was using Bootstrap Carousel but it's creating a glitch problem so I need to build this carousel without Bootstrap.

I've tried `@object.each_with_index` but I don't how for example if I choose image 2, image 3, etc. how to allow that to become the main image when the images are not static.

Here's my code:

```
 <% @car.pictures.each do |pic| %>              
       <%= image_tag(pic.picture.normal.url, class: 'show-main-pic img-responsive', id:"zoom_03", "data-zoom-image" => "#{pic.picture}") %>    


      <% end %>                     
  <!-- Indicators -->
                          <div id="gallery_01" >
                            <% @car.pictures.each_with_index do |small, index| %>
                                  <%= link_to "", "data-image"=> "#{small.picture}", "data-zoom-image" => "#{small.picture}" do %> 

                                  <%= image_tag(small.picture.thumb.url, class: (index == 0 ? 'elevatezoom-gallery active' : 'elevatezoom-gallery')) %>   

                                  <% end %>
                                <% end %>
                          </div>
```

Any ideas how I can build this?

Comment: in each item just provide some data attribute data/id/class and track it from jquery...
also if you don't have the idea about dynamic content use first/last item for special effect

Comment: @VivekSingh Just added my code.  Can you provide more detailed solution?

Answer (score 0):

Main image:

```
<% main_pic = @car.pictures.first %>     
<%= image_tag(main_pic.picture.normal.url, class: 'show-main-pic img-responsive', id:"zoom_03", "data-zoom-image" => "#{main_pic.picture}") %>
```

Collection:

```
<div id="gallery_01" >
   <% @car.pictures.each_with_index do |small, index| %>
      <%= link_to "", "data-image"=> "#{small.picture}", "data-zoom-image" => "#{small.picture}" do %> 
      <%= image_tag(small.picture.thumb.url, class: (index == 0 ? 'elevatezoom-gallery active' : 'elevatezoom-gallery')) %>   
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Main image you can just take any of the record currenly i choose first one.

Javascript logic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var zoomConfig = { zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
          zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
          zoomWindowWidth: 300,
          zoomWindowHeight: 300, 
          borderColour: "#142038",
          lensBorder: 0.5,
          responsive: true, }; 
          var image = $('#gallery_01 a');
          var zoomImage = $('img#zoom_03');

              zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);//initialise zoom

image.on('click', function(){
  // Remove old instance od EZ
  $('.zoomContainer').remove();
  zoomImage.removeData('elevateZoom');
  // Update source for images
  zoomImage.attr('src', $(this).data('image'));
  zoomImage.data('zoom-image', $(this).data('zoom-image'));
  // Reinitialize EZ
  zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So I tried this but the problem is when the new image is chosen from the gallery, it keeps reverting back to the first image no matter what. Any ideas?